# Sliding tab option for existing tabhost

Tags: android

I have developed an `Android` app using `tabhost`. I just want to add swipe option to slide the tabs like "facebook app". I have used two tabs as an `activity` not `fragment`.

Is there any option to do that? I read many posts but they have used `fragment` or `viewpager`.

In my app, I have used activities only.

```
TabHostWindow = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
final TabSpec TabMenu1 = TabHostWindow.newTabSpec("One");
TabSpec TabMenu2 = TabHostWindow.newTabSpec("Two");
TabMenu1.setIndicator("TAB1");
TabMenu1.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity_1.class));
TabMenu2.setIndicator("TAB2");
TabMenu2.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity_2.class));
TabHostWindow.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
TabHostWindow.addTab(TabMenu1);
TabHostWindow.addTab(TabMenu2);
```

This is a small snipped to explain how I have used `tabhost`.

Thank you!

Comment: i have to use viewpager for that

Comment: Why don't you try swipe tab layout? Refer mention link for this http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-create-android-swipe-views-tabs/

Comment: Thanks, but my question is, is there any way to do with activity not fragments.